# Jira Java Rest Client: how to unassign user?

Tags: java, rest, jira

For some reason the Jira Java Rest Client seems to be Atlassian's best kept secret.

After many experiments I am able to do most of the things I want to: transition tasks, link them, modify values (summary, description, labels). One thing I cannot get it to do is to unassign issues.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
Map<String, FieldInput> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("assignee", new FieldInput("assignee", null));
IssueInput input = new IssueInput(map);
client.getIssueClient().updateIssue(i.getKey(), input).claim();
```

Instead of null I tried "null", "unassigned", "", "-1". I also tried querying for the user. In most cases the program crashes, with null it proceeds, but the issue remains unchanged.

How to set assignee to "Unassigned" with this API? I am using version 4.0.0.